# postgresql Найти позицию слова в строке

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, select, plpgsql

У меня есть таблица с двумя полями следующего вида:

```
   ID           FIO
Ad1234      Иванов|Баранов|Крюков
Ac5434      Крюков|Baranov|Крылов
Dr287       Крюков|Ivanov|Баранов
```

Мне нужно с помощью PostgreSQL получить таблицу вида

```
   ID     Иванов    Баранов   Крюков   Крылов         FIO     
Ad1234      1          2        3        0      Иванов|Баранов|Крюков
Ac5434      0          2        1        3      Крюков|Baranov|Крылов
Dr287       2          3        1        0      Крюков|Ivanov|Баранов
```

Т.е. найти позицию каждой фамилии с строке

Comment: Получается Вам также требуется распознавать транслит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На языке `plpgsql` функция `strpos(string, substring)` возвращает номер вхождения в подстроке Например для `strpos('high', 'ig')` функция вернет `2`. Можно сделать так:

1) Получаем эти числа для всех фамилий.

2) Если равно 1, то пишем первым номером, если больше запоминаем для дальнейшего сравнения.

3) Сравниваем их между собой, выстраиваем по порядку.